# MassTransit Depedency Injection and capturing BrokerUnreachableException

Tags: masstransit

Using Docker containers; ASPNETCore 2.1.1 and NETCore 2.1; broker is RabbitMQ.
Our idea on during container/service startup, and RabbitMQ is down, is to try and capture the BrokerUnreachableException and try to call IHostedService.StartAsync() again after a period of time.

a. Where would we capture the exception?
b. Is this a good strategy?

Comment: If your service processes messages and RMQ is down, what is the point to start your service, it will not be healthy anyway? MT will try to reconnect several times. You should crash your service or, if you use k8s, provide a healthcheck, so k8s can keep restarting the pod until RMQ is back.

In addition, I guarantee that your service will go down hundreds time more often than RMQ. We never experienced RMQ outage, except networking failures, in production, for many years.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We've decided to go with a RMQ cluster and a check long before the service is launched.